# add array of keys as property on obj as accumulator by reduce?

Tags: javascript

i have array of keys that i want to add as property with calculated val(not including on code) on empty object like this by reduce:

```
const f = ['a','b','c'].reduce((obj,key) => obj[key]='', {})
```

i was expecting the obj is the accumulator {} so i added properties that way? how do i make this work by reduce?

i was expecting and want it to result like this for that code:

```
{ a:'',  b:'', c:'' }
```

but my code only results to empty string on console. how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value that the reduce callback returns will be the accumulator in the next iteration. So, in your code, `obj` only refers to the object in the first iteration - on the next iteration, it refers to what `obj[key] = ''` resolves to, which is the empty string.

Return the object instead:

```js
const f = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((obj, key) => {
  obj[key] = '';
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(f);
```

You could use `Object.fromEntries` instead, if you wanted (though, it's very new, so for good cross-browser support, include a polyfill):

```js
const f = Object.fromEntries(
  ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(key => [key, ''])
);
console.log(f);
```

Comment: Or don't use `reduce`, as it's really not the tool for this job. (But the OP specifically asked for it, so...)

Comment: @iamgpbaculio - A simple loop: `const obj = {}; for (const key of ['a', 'b', 'c']) { obj[key] = ''; }` `reduce` is over-complicated for 9/10ths of what people use it for. One good indicator `reduce` isn't the right tool is when you're always returning the same thing (in this case, the object).

Comment: One argument I saw against using `reduce` for this sort of thing (before `Object.entries` was a thing): https://gist.github.com/brigand/19ce8809ca34646b9d640779be06a955